# When 2 different images are uploaded to 2 different folders,then the images are uploaded.but the thumbs are not created

Tags: image, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, image-resizing, codeigniter-3

Here is my controller function, please help me to create the thumbs of both images. Only the images are uploaded to the folder. i created a function named resize to create the thumbs. that's also given in the controller.

```
public function add() {

    $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
    $this->load->helper('file');
    $this->load->library('form_validation');


    $this->form_validation->set_rules('txtPrdname', 'Product Name', 'trim|required|htmlspecialchars');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('sbPrdcategory', 'Product Category', 'trim|required|htmlspecialchars');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('sbPrduser', 'Managing User', 'trim|required|htmlspecialchars');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('txtPrdprofile', 'Product Profile', 'trim|required|htmlspecialchars');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {

        $data_view["error"] = "";

        $this->load->view('moderator/templates/header');
        $this->load->view('moderator/templates/sidebar');
        $this->load->view('moderator/b2bproduct_add', $data_view);
        $this->load->view('moderator/templates/footer');

    } else {

        // Image uploading codes

        $config['upload_path'] = 'assets/images/b2bproduct';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|jpeg|png';
        $config['max_size'] = '1000';
        $config['max_width'] = '2024';
        $config['max_height'] = '1768';
        $config['overwrite'] = TRUE;
        $config['remove_spaces'] = TRUE;

        if (isset($_FILES['filePrdimage']['name'])) {
            $config['file_name'] = substr(md5(time()), 0, 28) . $_FILES['filePrdimage']['name'];
        }

        $this->load->library('upload');

        $this->upload->initialize($config);

        if (!$this->upload->do_upload('filePrdimage')) {

            //no file uploaded or failed upload

            $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

        } else {

            $dat = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());

            $this->load->library('upload');
            $this->upload->initialize($config);
            $this->resize($dat['upload_data']['full_path'], 'assets/images/b2bproduct/thump/' . $dat['upload_data']['file_name'], 180, 400);
        }

        if (empty($dat['upload_data']['file_name'])) {
            $prdimage = '';
        } else {
            $prdimage = $dat['upload_data']['file_name'];
        }    

        // End Image uploading Codes
        // Logo uploading codes

        $config['upload_path'] = 'assets/images/b2blogo';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|jpeg|png';
        $config['max_size'] = '1000';
        $config['max_width'] = '2024';
        $config['max_height'] = '1768';
        $config['overwrite'] = TRUE;
        $config['remove_spaces'] = TRUE;

        if (isset($_FILES['filePrdlogo']['name'])) {
            $config['file_name'] = substr(md5(time()), 0, 28) . $_FILES['filePrdlogo']['name'];
        }

        $this->load->library('upload');

        $this->upload->initialize($config);

        if (!$this->upload->do_upload('filePrdlogo')) {

            //no file uploaded or failed upload

            $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

        } else {

            $dat1 = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());

            $this->load->library("upload",$config);

            $this->resize($dat1['upload_data']['full_path'], 'assets/images/b2blogo/thump/' . $dat1['upload_data']['file_name'], 180, 400);
        }

        if (empty($dat1['upload_data']['file_name'])) {
            $prdlogo = '';
        } else {
            $prdlogo = $dat1['upload_data']['file_name'];
        }

        // End Logo uploading Codes         

        $data = array(
            'prd_name' => $this->input->post('txtPrdname'),
            'prd_category' => $this->input->post('sbPrdcategory'),
            'prd_user' => $this->input->post('sbPrduser'),
            'prd_profile' => $this->input->post('txtPrdprofile'),
            'prd_oem' => $this->input->post('rbtnPrdoem'),
            'prd_protype' => $this->input->post('rbtnPrdprotype'),
            'prd_image' => $prdimage,
            'prd_ranktype' => $this->input->post('sbPrdranktype'),
            'prd_points' => $this->input->post('txtPrdpoints'),
            'prd_extrakey' => $this->input->post('txtPrdextrakey'),
            'prd_dated' => time(),
            'prd_ipadd' => $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']
        );

        $result_id = $this->b2bproduct_model->add($data);

        if ($result_id) {

            redirect(base_url() . 'moderator/b2bproduct/view/' . $result_id, 'refresh');

        } else {

            $data_view["error"] = "Data can't insert due to database error";

            $this->load->view('moderator/templates/header');

            $this->load->view('moderator/templates/sidebar');

            $this->load->view('moderator/b2bproduct_add', $data_view);

            $this->load->view('moderator/templates/footer');

        }

    }

}
```

Resize function

```
public function resize($source, $destination, $width, $height) {
    $config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
    $config['source_image'] = $source;
    $config['create_thumb'] = TRUE;
    $config['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
    $config['width'] = $width;
    $config['height'] = $height;
    $config['new_image'] = $destination;
    $this->load->library('image_lib', $config);
    $this->image_lib->resize();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you are loading library two times in your `function add` please load it one time probably at the top of function.

in resize use `$this->image_lib->initialize($config)` as below

```
public function resize($source, $destination, $width, $height) {
    $config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
    $config['source_image'] = $source;
    $config['create_thumb'] = TRUE;
    $config['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
    $config['width'] = $width;
    $config['height'] = $height;
    $config['new_image'] = $destination;
    $this->load->library('image_lib');
    $this->image_lib->initialize($config);
    $this->image_lib->resize();
}
```

Comment: :) dont need to overtake. i appreciate your talent.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that the folders for your thumbs (`assets/images/b2bproduct/thump/` and `assets/images/b2blogo/thump/`) do not exist?

It is very likely the reason to be a simple spelling mistake like `thump` instead of `thumb`.

EDIT:

You really don't have to load the `upload` and `image_lib` libraries so many times. Do it once at the beginning. After that you can use `$this->upload->initialize($config);` or `$this->image_lib->initialize($config);` to all these places where now you are trying to re-load the libraries.

To make your code works you should at least add `$this->image_lib->initialize($config);` before `$this->image_lib->resize();` in your `resize` function.

Comment: thump is the folder name only.

Comment: Yes, but is the `thump` folder exist in these destinations? If there is no such folder the `image_lib` library won't create the thumb.

Comment: Man, I rebuilt exactly your example to find out the solution. See the edited answer!

Comment: Don't forget to mark one of the answers as the correct one or at least to up-vote  the answers which helped you ;)

Comment: Actually, am asking questions first time in stack overflow.  Definitely vote for the answer that helped me... :) Done